# How can I get the text below this hamburger image to flow from the left of the page?

Tags: html, css

The body text in this page flows from a point not only below the hamburger image but also to the right of it. How can I get it to flow from closer to the left page edge, so that it will look OK on smaller screens? I have tried adjusting margin and padding settings. I am trying to keep this JavaScript-free.

```css
/* Navigation Menu - Background */
.navigation {
  /* critical sizing and position styles */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  /* non-critical appearance styles */
  list-style: none;
  background: #000;
}
/* Navigation Menu - List items */
.nav-item {
  /* non-critical appearance styles */
  width: 200px;
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.nav-item a {
  /* non-critical appearance styles */
  display: block;
  padding: 1em; 
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color 0.2s, background 0.5s;
}
.nav-item a:hover {
  color: #c74438;
}
/* Site Wrapper - Everything that isn't navigation */
.site-wrap {
  /* Critical position and size styles */
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  background-color: white; /* Needs a background or else the nav will show through */
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 2;
  z-index: 1;
  /* non-critical appearance styles */
  padding: 4em;
  padding-left: -4em;
  background-size: 200%;
}
/* Nav Trigger */
.nav-trigger {
  /* critical styles - hide the checkbox input */
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
label[for="nav-trigger"] {
  /* critical positioning styles */
  position: fixed;
  left: 15px; top: 15px;
  z-index: 2;
  /* non-critical appearance styles */
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: url(http://imgur.com/S0q57Jd.jpg);
  background-size: contain;
}
/* Make the Magic Happen */
.nav-trigger + label, .site-wrap {
  transition: left 0.2s;
}
.nav-trigger:checked + label {
  left: 215px;
}
.nav-trigger:checked ~ .site-wrap {
  left: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
body {
    /* Without this, the body has excess horizontal scroll when the menu is open */
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
/* Additional non-critical styles */
h1, h3, p {
  margin: 0 auto 1em;
}
h1 {font-size: 1.125em;}
h3 {font-size: 1em;}
p {font-size: 0.8125em;}
code {
    padding: 2px;
    background: #ddd;
}
/* Micro reset */
*,*:before,*:after{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;padding:0;}
html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
```

```html
<body>
<ul class="navigation">
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Two</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Four</a></li>
 </ul>
 <input type="checkbox" id="nav-trigger" class="nav-trigger" />
 <label for="nav-trigger"></label>
 <div class="site-wrap">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi vero nisi eos sed qui natus, ut eius reprehenderit error nesciunt veniam aliquam nulla itaque labore obcaecati molestiae eveniet, perferendis provident amet perspiciatis expedita accusantium! Eveniet, quos voluptas et, labore natus, saepe unde est nulla sit eaque tempore debitis accusantium. Recusandae.</p>
  <p>Dolorem aliquam a libero reiciendis obcaecati doloribus ipsa eos laudantium, dicta in! Odit iure ut ratione, dolorum cupiditate perferendis voluptatum sapiente, dignissimos sunt necessitatibus, reprehenderit consequatur dolorem. Aliquam veniam quaerat, pariatur deserunt reiciendis vero vitae, repellat omnis sequi dolor nesciunt. Nihil similique alias impedit, obcaecati eligendi delectus voluptatum! Ipsum, vel.</p>
  <p>Sint, perspiciatis nemo aut, rerum excepturi deleniti modi quos nihil corporis eum, maiores soluta labore, consectetur eligendi nesciunt. Placeat, incidunt! Illum placeat eligendi, veritatis consectetur eum! Dolor obcaecati minima ab placeat voluptatem neque modi doloribus, magnam qui voluptate eaque in. Nulla expedita hic porro architecto facere officiis vitae numquam, dolor!</p>
  <p>Perferendis quis ea incidunt ducimus nisi voluptate natus. Repellat asperiores quod rerum rem quos blanditiis enim modi, veniam voluptas a facilis! Velit cum omnis, voluptatum eum inventore! Corrupti, suscipit, neque distinctio expedita est laboriosam cum aliquid minus tempora quaerat officia possimus unde vel deleniti eaque fugit accusamus iusto dolorum natus. </p>
 </div>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
.site-wrap {
  ...
  padding: 4em;
  padding-left: -4em;
  ...
}
```

to this

```
.site-wrap {
  ...
  padding: 4em 0;
  ...
}
```

Delete the line `padding-left: -4em;`

You can have multiple values in the `padding` property:

> If the `padding` property has four values:
>
> - **padding: 25px 50px 75px 100px;**
>
>   - top padding is 25px
>   - right padding is 50px
>   - bottom padding is 75px
>   - left padding is 100px
>
> If the `padding` property has three values:
>
> - **padding: 25px 50px 75px;**
>
>   - top padding is 25px
>   - right and left paddings are 50px
>   - bottom padding is 75px
>
> If the `padding` property has two values:
>
> - **padding: 25px 50px;**
>
>   - top and bottom paddings are 25px
>   - right and left paddings are 50px
>
> If the `padding` property has one value:
>
> - **padding: 25px;**
>
>   - all four paddings are 25px

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp

Comment: Many thanks, @Alic: an excellent answer which tells me exactly what I needed to know about padding.

Answer (score 0):

You have a 4em padding on .site-wrap pretty sure that's it

Comment: Many thanks, @KarimCossutti. Removing that padding has solved half the problem. The text now starts flowing from the left page edge, but it has jumped up to start from the top of the page, interfering with the image.

Comment: when you define padding with a single value like `padding: 4em` it's like saying padding top, right, bottom and left are 4em, i guess you deleted the whole thing, and that's like saying no padding, what you want is `padding: 4em 0` which is lika saying padding top and bottom 4em left and right 0.